# Custom UIalertView in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Do anywho know a custom UIAlertView class what is working in iOS5 ?
I'm looking for a class like TSAlertView, with that I will able to put 2 buttons stacked into alert.
(   http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tsalertview   )

Thanx for help.

Answer (score 2):

`UIAlertView` in `iOS 5` has `UIAlertViewStyles`

```
UIAlertViewStyleDefault
UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput
UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput
UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput
```

**EDIT** Sorry for misunderstanding your problem. The alert view shown in the linked page is extremely easy to reproduce. Here's what I came up with:

[image]

I implemented this with a category for convenience but you could easily just implement it elsewhere. Basically what you do is add a cancel button and then hide it. That way there are three buttons as far as the alert view is concerned and it does not place the two visible buttons side by side. The category implementation is as follows:

```
-(void)showWithCutCancelButton{
    // Make sure alert view will look right
    if (self.cancelButtonIndex == -1 || self.numberOfButtons < 3) return;
    self.clipsToBounds = YES; // or else cancel button will still be visible
    [self show];
    // Shrink height to leave cancel button outside
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 64);
}
```

Then you show this by calling:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"Message here" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Option1", @"Option2", nil];
[alert showWithCutCancelButton];
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but it dont solves the problem with buttons side by side. I want to have they stacked.

Comment: @NJones This is a great solution! I have been playing around with it for a while, though, and can't find a way to get the Cancel button to display as the second button, with the dummy button as the third button, because in some cases I have one button and a cancel button that I would like to display, stacked. Have you been able to implement this solution as well?

Comment: @JPK That would be more complicated, but it is possible. Also is that what you are asking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9996975/927947)?

Comment: @NJones Yes, using your method, I wanted to try to get the cancel button at the bottom. I thought I should make it a new thread rather than tagging my new question onto an old one, when they are different.

Comment: @JPK I have posted an answer to your question here at that question.